# Ошибка `mon_enter': stack level too deep при запуске vagrant up

Tags: ruby, vagrant

Подскажите, пожауйста куда копать.
Запускаю **vagrant up** и получаю спустя какое-то время:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:186:in `mon_enter': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:212:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/repository.rb:75:in `find_ancestor'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/logger.rb:62:in `deal_with_inheritance'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/log4r-1.1.10/lib/log4r/logger.rb:36:in `initialize'
    from /home/spopov/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.9/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:12:in `new'
    from /home/spopov/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.9/gems/vagrant-triggers-0.5.3/lib/vagrant-triggers/action/trigger.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:122:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:122:in `finalize_action'
     ... 10180 levels...
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:525:in `hook'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:774:in `unload'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/bin/vagrant:185:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/bin/vagrant:185:in `<main>'
```

```
 INFO global: Vagrant version: 2.2.7
 INFO global: Ruby version: 2.4.9
 INFO global: RubyGems version: 2.6.14.4
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_ENV="1"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_EXECUTABLE="/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/bin/vagrant"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_EMBEDDED_DIR="/opt/vagrant/embedded"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_VERSION="2"
```

Comment: Видать, у вас где-то рекурсия.  Смотрите внимательно свой `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: я обложил логами весь файл, все норм, он полностью отработал для обоих нод и уже после - развалился